# How to modify path by code in eclipse workbench's title bar?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

There will be a path of current opened file in title bar of eclipse workbench. Like this:

[image]

But in eclipse plugin development, maybe open a editor that is not associated with any files. Thus, the path will be 'null', like as follow:

[image]

So, i would like **change the 'null'** of title bar in java code.
Thank you !

Comment: So go find that in the eclipse source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really possible to change the window title code which is set in `IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` an internal Eclipse class which does not have any way to customize this code.

The code expects `IWorkbenchPart.getTitleToolTip` to return a reasonable value which does not seem to be happening for this particular editor.

Comment: Yes, you should open a bug against Rational Team Concert to get this bug fixed.

Comment: Very appreciate of you. Use _getToolTipText()_ of class _IEditorInput_ can change window titile.